# TypeError: Failed to construct 'Touch': 1 argument required, but only 0 present

Tags: javascript, typescript, jasmine

**why i am getting this error?**
*i want to write a spec for one function, i wrote it but it shows above error*
**Here i added my code**

```js
describe("getcomponent funtion", function () {
    it("if statement", function () {
        let comp: any = { ej2_instances: [new Touch()] };
        expect(getComponent(comp, 'touch') instanceof Touch).toBe(true);
    });
    it("else statement", function () {
        let comp: any = { ej2_instances: [new Touch()] };
        expect(getComponent(comp, 'button') instanceof Touch).not.toBe(true);
    });
});
```

**this is error->**
* TypeError: Failed to construct 'Touch': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.

```
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (D:/ej2-base-library/spec/base.spec.js:166:42)
```

HeadlessChrome 61.0.3163 (Windows 10.0.0) getcomponent funtion else statement FAILED

```
    TypeError: Failed to construct 'Touch': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.

        at UserContext.<anonymous> (D:/ej2-base-library/spec/base.spec.js:170:42)*
```

Comment: Because Touch's constructor requires one argument, but you pass zero arguments.

Comment: i tried to give an argument but it did not work

Comment: Then give a [mcve] *of that*.

Comment: okay bro, i got a fix. thans for your support.

Answer (score 1):

You have to give argument to "touch" function like following:

```js
describe("getcomponent funtion", function () {
    it("if statement", function () {
        let elem:any =createElement('div', { id: 'test' });
        let comp: any = { ej2_instances: [new Touch(elem)] };
        expect(getComponent(comp, 'touch') instanceof Touch).toBe(true);
    });
    it("else statement", function () {
        let elem:any =createElement('div', { id: 'test' });
        let comp: any = { ej2_instances: [new Touch(elem)] };
        expect(getComponent(comp, 'button') instanceof Touch).toBe(false);
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried it, but it show error on that element "elem"

Comment: ohh thanks a lot bro, i did not import it, now it worked. thanks.